# Error in @(filename)readAndPreprocessImage(filename)

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, training-data

I tried

```
trainingFeatures=activations(net,trainingSet,featureLayer,'MiniBatchSize',32,'OutputAs','columns');
```

but it gave me  this error:

```
imds.ReadFcn=
@(filename)readAndPreprocessImage(filename)

Undefined function 'readAndPreprocessImage' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in @(filename)readAndPreprocessImage(filename)
```

I am assuming that its the issue of filename, what should I put there?

Comment: Where is the `readAndPreprocessImage()` function defined? This anonymous function you're creating - `@(filename)readAndPreprocessImage(filename)` is just a little wrapper function that calls a global named function named `readAndPreprocessImage`. (And since it doesn't do anything else, why even have it? Just do `@readAndPreprocessImage` instead.)

Comment: I used this function above that code imds.ReadFcn=@(filename)readAndPreprocessImage(filename);

Comment: types={'menorah','sunflower'};
imds=imageDatastore(fullfile(rootFolder,types),'LabelSource','foldernames');
imds.ReadFcn=@(filename)readAndPreprocessImage(filename);
tbl=countEachLabel(imds);
minSetCount=min(tbl{:,2});
imds=splitEachLabel(imds,minSetCount,'randomize');
net=alexnet();
[trainingSet, testSet]=splitEachLabel(imds,0.7,'randomize');
trainingFeatures=activations(net,trainingSet,featureLayer,'MiniBatchSize',32,'OutputAs','columns');